# relationship of the two attributes

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

Assume, two attributes have a correlation of 0.02; what does this tell you about the relationship of the two attributes? Answer the same question assuming the correlation is -0.98.

Comment: Looks you copy-pasted from some quiz !!

Answer (score 0):

.02 means that the two attributes are not strongly correlated.  As in, they have very little to do with each other.

For instance, let's talk about the level of someone's craziness compared to the number of cats they own.  The more cats, the crazier the person is.  That is a high correlation, because the two things are related: number of cats and craziness.  The correlation would be around .98 , because the two things are strongly correlated.

A weak correlation of around .02 as above would be how often I fart in a day vs the price of gasoline in India.  It's .02 because the two are not correlated at all.  The closer to 0 a correlation is, the less likely it is that the two variables have anything to do with each other.  The closer to 1, the more likely it is that the variables have something to do with each other.

A negative correlation, like -.98, means that two things are related but in an opposite way: like if you exercise more you decrease risk of cancer.  As exercise goes up, risk of cancer goes down.  The two are strongly correlated but in a negative way.  They do not rise and fall together, when one rises the other falls.